# Can't install libpq-dev, ubuntu 10.10 and postgres 9

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, ubuntu

I need some headers from the dev-version of postgres 9, which is contained in libpq-dev, for installing the `pg` gem, but when I execute:

> sudo apt-get install libpq-dev

I get the result:

> The following packages have unmet dependencies:
>    libpq-dev : Depends: libpq5 (= 8.4.7-0ubuntu0.10.10) but 9.0.1-1~lucid is to be installed

When I tried to remove `libpq5` (to reinstall it correctly?), it threatened to remove postgresql-9.0:

> The following packages will be REMOVED:
>     libpq5 pgadmin3 php5-pgsql postgresql-9.0 postgresql-client-9.0

Does anybody know how to solve this problem? Thanks.

Answer (score 6):

I solved this for myself by running:

```
sudo apt-get remove libpq5
sudo apt-get install libpq-dev
```

Automatically fixed dependencies.

Comment: worked like a charm...

Answer (score 0):

Finally I've reinstalled all that stuff, first I've removed old libpq5 and it's deleted all postgres-* packages, after that I've reinstalled postgresql-9.0 by downloading its binary from http://www.enterprisedb.com/products/pgdownload.do, and by accident postgresql-client-8.4 has been installed too. But all these things now works together.

and

> gem install pg

was successful